# Kafka logs huge size with Hyperledger Fabric on Docker on EC2

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric

I am having a bit of a problem with an attempt of a Hyperledger Fabric PoC on an AWS EC2 environment.

I have my network set up with 3 orgs, 3 peers (1 peer each), 2 orderers, 4 kafka's,  3 zookeeper's.
Each org is located in a different instance, and Ordering + Kafka + Zookeeper are sharing the same instance.
I'm also using Node SDK 1.2 on a different instance.

Everything seemed to be working fine until I tried a performance test using Artillery from another instance. 
First of all, I couldn't get a high throughput performance when I tried a test with many simultaneous users (around 50), the network seemed to collapse. Graphics from Artillery show unstable performance and then it completely dies.

Now second and most important, when I lowered the load to 5 simultaneous users, performance problems disappeared but I noticed that after a short while the instance with Ordering services, Kafka and Zk **runs out of disk space**. I did some research and found a huge amount of data under my /var/lib/docker/overlay2 directory.

In some of the bigger containers I found a kafka-logs directory with 1gb .log files. I managed to nano one and it showed some certificates as following

> BEGIN CERTIFICATE
>
> [...]
>
> END CERTIFICATE
>   repeat

It was splitting files at 1gb and storing many of them, let's say 3Gb in 30 minutes.

I tried using docker log rotate in my compose and also in daemon.json:

```
logging:
   driver: "json-file"
   options:
      max-size: "1m"
      max-file: "3"
```

It actually worked on the directory /var/lib/docker/containers where .log files are being limited to 1Mb and 3 files max. But the problem with overlay2 persists.

My docker composer for kafka:

```
kafka:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-kafka:0.4.10
    restart: always
    environment:
      - KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES=103809024 # 99 * 1024 * 1024 B
      - KAFKA_REPLICA_FETCH_MAX_BYTES=103809024 # 99 * 1024 * 1024 B
      - KAFKA_UNCLEAN_LEADER_ELECTION_ENABLE=false
      - KAFKA_MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS=2
      - KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR=3
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper0.example.com:2181,zookeeper1.example.com:2181,zookeeper2.example.com:2181
      - log.retention.bytes = 1000000
      - log.retention.ms = 30000
    logging:
     driver: "json-file"
     options:
      max-size: "1m"
      max-file: "3"
```

As you can see I also tried log.retention.bytes = 1000000 but I'm not sure that's the correct usage of the params because it didn't have any effect.

Also restarted docker service. I've been struggling with this for a week so I've already tried the most common solutions that I found online.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The configuration parameter should be:

```
KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_BYTES=1000000
KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_MS=30000
```

Refer to the fabric-test kafka.yaml:

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-test/blob/master/feature-upgrade/dc-orderer-kafka-base.yml